# suggestions in partitioning root space to create space for a second distro

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, fat32

I need to shring space of root partition on my disk to create a new partition for the installation of another distro (I have now Ubuntu/Kde Plasma and I want to have a dual boot with EndeavourOS). I think I know how to do this, but since it is quite a risky procedure, I may want to ask your advices!

The configuration is apparently simple
(both GParted and KDE partition manager gives me this:)

> unallocated

2MB

> /dev/nvme0n1p1

mount point: /boot/EFI     (fat32)         300MB (5.24MB used)

> /dev/nvme0n1p2

mount point: /    (ext4)         238.17GB (127.08GB used)

> unallocated

7.20MB

---

But when "lsblk" gives me quite a number of loops, that's why I prefer to ask before loosing data:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0 162,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop1         7:1    0  63,6M  1 loop /snap/handbrake-jz/142
loop2         7:2    0    68K  1 loop /snap/acrordrdc/53
loop3         7:3    0    68K  1 loop /snap/acrordrdc/62
loop4         7:4    0   285M  1 loop /snap/atom/282
loop5         7:5    0 284,9M  1 loop /snap/atom/286
loop6         7:6    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop7         7:7    0 114,9M  1 loop /snap/core/13741
loop8         7:8    0   115M  1 loop /snap/core/13886
loop9         7:9    0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2560
loop10        7:10   0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566
loop11        7:11   0  63,2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop12        7:12   0  63,2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1634
loop13        7:13   0  33,2M  1 loop /snap/crystal/1349
loop14        7:14   0  33,2M  1 loop /snap/crystal/1367
loop15        7:15   0   6,3M  1 loop /snap/curl/1093
loop16        7:16   0   6,3M  1 loop /snap/curl/1113
loop17        7:17   0 164,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop18        7:18   0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop19        7:19   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop20        7:20   0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop21        7:21   0  81,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop22        7:22   0   140K  1 loop /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop23        7:23   0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop24        7:24   0  29,2M  1 loop /snap/node/6800
loop25        7:25   0  29,2M  1 loop /snap/node/6853
loop26        7:26   0 101,5M  1 loop /snap/p7zip-desktop/220
loop27        7:27   0 184,4M  1 loop /snap/signal-desktop/398
loop28        7:28   0 141,1M  1 loop /snap/skype/231
loop29        7:29   0 184,1M  1 loop /snap/signal-desktop/397
loop30        7:30   0 141,5M  1 loop /snap/skype/234
loop31        7:31   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17029
loop32        7:32   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17336
loop33        7:33   0 303,1M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/16
loop34        7:34   0 303,1M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/18
loop35        7:35   0 322,9M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/14
loop36        7:36   0 322,9M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/19
loop37        7:37   0 347,1M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-runtime/315
loop38        7:38   0   347M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-runtime/316
loop39        7:39   0   2,5M  1 loop /snap/ymuse/61
loop40        7:40   0   250M  1 loop /snap/zoom-client/170
loop41        7:41   0   2,5M  1 loop /snap/ymuse/54
loop42        7:42   0 352,4M  1 loop /snap/zoom-client/175
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 238,2G  0 part /
```

and so "fdisk -l"

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 162,87 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 63,59 MiB, 66674688 bytes, 130224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 68 KiB, 69632 bytes, 136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 68 KiB, 69632 bytes, 136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 285,05 MiB, 298893312 bytes, 583776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 284,93 MiB, 298774528 bytes, 583544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 114,93 MiB, 120508416 bytes, 235368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SX8200PNP                         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 729952F6-973B-7E48-A50F-47CBB14D3987

Dispositivo     Start      Fine   Settori   Size Tipo
/dev/nvme0n1p1   4096    618495    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 618496 500103449 499484954 238,2G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 114,99 MiB, 120573952 bytes, 235496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

...
```

I want to create a new partition (~70GB) taking space from "/dev/nvme0n1p2" (free space 110.08GB), can I indicate the new sectors considering them as being proportionally related to the space? I mean, if this is the partition:

> /dev/nvme0n1p2 (start) 618496 (end) 500103449 (total sectors)
> 499484954 238,2G

can I set the things like

> /dev/nvme0n1p2 (start) 618496 (end) 353300970 (total sectors) 352682475 168,17G

> /dev/nvme0n2p1 (start) 353300971 (end) 500103449 (total sectors) 146802479 70,0G

Can I do that with fdisk? I know I can do it directly during the installation of the new distro, but it seems to me a bit risky and I wanted to do this separately. Any suggestions?

thanks
R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: It would help a lot to see a screen shot of the output of Gparted. The location of the partitions in relation to each other is important. It can be seen much easier in the GUI app.

Comment: yes, unfortunately it seems I am not allowed to add pictures (I guess because I am a beginner here).

Comment: thank you guiverc! So, I guess the most secure process is with Gparted live, isn't it?

Comment: If it was me, I'd just resize using the tool I know best, as there are many that will do the job, but most problems will be caused by mistakes & using the tool you know best I feel would limit those mistakes. Ubuntu has ISOs with 5 installers available, each has *pros* & *cons* but Endeavour is off-topic here, but you could do it with various of the Ubuntu installer tools (*I know as I'm involved in QA & do it often with them*), but as stated I'd use the tool you're most familiar with.

Comment: Besides, the way to do this partitioning. I wanted to understand if I can consider sectors and bytes as linearly equivalent. That is to say that if I have for instance a partition 50% full (with total sectors from 1 to 100.000), I can –in principle– create another partition from it which starts at sector 50001 without losing data?

Comment: Your *logic* may apply assuming you've created specific file-system(s) in the partition, and *never* deleted any files within it, as file-space/inodes allocated to files can be anywhere on the partition & the *fs* involved can influence how sectors/inodes are allocated... ie. don't make assumptions if you value your data; reduce the partition size from the partition table

Comment: i will do that. thank you

Comment: Just as an update. Everything is done. Partitions resized successfully! thanks to eveyone.